# Python find first of multiple (single character) substrings

Tags: python

What's the most Pythonic way to find the first of multiple single character substrings (if any) in a string?

To be clear, a string can contain multiple characters of interest and I want to find the first one - any one, I don't care which & don't need to know which. I just want to know that one of those characters occurred and the first point in the string where any of them occurred (thus, clearly not a dupe of the suggested question).

```
endDigitPos = digitText.find(['u', ' ', ')', '}', '/*'])
```

Isn't doing it

I am generically parsing C code - any C code. I am actually looking for hex strings, which start with `0x`; having found that, I want to find the end of the hex string, which will be a space a close bracket, a space, a `u` if it is unsigned, or the end of line.

`digitText` starts `0x` and ends with one of those chars.

The code above gives

```
endDigitPos = digitText.find(['u', ' ', ')', '}', '/*'])
TypeError: must be str, not list
```

Comment: Could you add an example of inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: Why would `.find` do it? Do you even have the algorithm established?

Comment: Do you want to find the first substring that occurs in the string, or the substring that occurs in the string first? In other words, if the string is `"abc"` and the substrings are `["c", "a"]`, should the result be 2 (where the "c" is) or 0 (where the "a" is)?

Comment: Where the `c` is; I have updated the question and hope that it is clear now (thanks for your help +1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No idea of whether this is "the most pythonic" way, but one option would be

```
index = next(i for i,c in enumerate(s) if c in {'u', ' ', ')', '}', '/'})
```

**Note**: This will raise a `StopIteration` in case no item is found. Adapt as needed depending on what you would like to have as the "item is not there" case.

**Note2:** As Patrick pointed out in the comments, this only works for single-characters, so if you need the multi-substring approach go for his proposed solution

Comment: Won't this fail in the case of multiple character substrings like `/*`?

Comment: Ah, didn't see the multi-character case, I just copy-pasted the list and tested with `u`. Yes, this won't work for multi-character strings

Comment: I can live with just the `/` as start of comment.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think there's anything that does this out of the box, but it's pretty easy to implement as regex

```
import re

def find_many(instring, *substrings):
    pat = re.compile('|'.join([re.escape(s) for s in substrings]))
    match = pat.search(instring)
    if match is None:
        return -1
    else:
        return match.start() 

substrings = ['u', ' ', ')', '}', '/*']
find_many('aaa/*', *substrings)  #  3
find_many('aaab', *substrings)   # -1
find_many('uaaa/*', *substrings) #  0
```

Comment: You can use `match.start()` instead of `match.span()[0]`.